# Find non secure post / form data with ZAP proxy

Tags: owasp, zap

Is it possible to detect the possibility to send unsecured POST / FORM data to a non-ssl address with ZAP proxy?

Comment: It is a bit unclear, you mean to test if the request is sent to a non-https endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 alpha quality passive scan rules that check for http -> https posts and the other way round: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsPscanrulesAlphaPscanalpha#http-to-https-insecure-transition-in-form-post

Just install the alpha passive scan rules from the marketplace.